# find elements with "simple_HTML_DOM" and merge them

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to extract all p-elements of a html-string via simple_html_dom. The order of the p-elements should be obtained.

```
<section class="box_1">
    <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="class"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text Level 2</p>
                <p>More Text Level 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="class"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text Level 2</p>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Text Level 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

BUT all p-elements in the same content-container should be merged together.

I tried this:

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) { 
    if ($element->parent()->parent()) {
        $class= $element->parent()->parent()->getAttribute('class');
        if ($class=="box_3") $level = 3;
        else if ($class=="box_2") $level = 2;
        else if ($class=="box_1") $level = 1;
    }
    else { $level = 0; }
    $array_content_element = array("level" => $level, "inhalt" => $element->plaintext);
    array_push($array_content, $array_content_element);
}
```

But with this i.e. "Text Level 2" and "More Text Level 2" would be handled as two elements. But they should be merged to "Text Level 2\nMore Text Level 2" and this should be handled as ONE element.

So in this example the result should be an array with three elements (instead of four).

**Update:** I forgot something. There can be p-elements outside of the section-elements. Please have a look at the following "Lorem ipsum".

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<section class="box_1">
    <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="class"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text Level 2</p>
                <p>More Text Level 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="class"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Text Level 2</p>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Text Level 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<section class="box_1">
    <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
       <p>Text Level 1</p>
    </div>
</section>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

These p-elements should be treated like the others (summarize the p-elements of one block). In this case level = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first determine which is which. Is it an orphan or not. Then, just change to next key/batch if it reaches the end of the batch (no more `p` tags left). Consider this example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html_string = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><section class="box_1"> <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header> <div class="content"> <div class="box_2"> <div class="class"></div> <div class="content"> <p>Text Level 2</p> <p>More Text Level 2</p> </div> </div> <div class="box_2"> <div class="class"></div> <div class="content"> <p>Text Level 2</p> <div class="box_3"> <div class="content"> <p>Text Level 3</p> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div></section><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><section class="box_1"> <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header> <div class="content"> <p>Text Level 1</p> </div></section><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>';
$html = str_get_html($html_string);
$array_content = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($html->find('p') as $key => $tag) {
    if($tag->parent()->tag == 'root') {
        // if alone p tag
        if(!isset($array_content[$index])) {
            $array_content[$index] = array('level' => 0, 'inhalt' => $tag->innertext);
        } else {
            $array_content[$index]['inhalt'] .= "\n" . $tag->innertext;
        }

    } elseif($tag->parent->class == 'content') {
        // handle tags with proper parents
        $type = $tag->parent->parent->class;
         switch($type) {
            case 'box_1': $level = 1; break;
            case 'box_2': $level = 2; break;
            case 'box_3': $level = 3; break;
        }

        if(!isset($array_content[$index])) {
            $array_content[$index] = array('level' => $level, 'inhalt' => $tag->innertext);
        } else {
            $array_content[$index]['inhalt'] .= "\n" . $tag->innertext;
        }

    }

    // change index if set to next batch
    if(!isset($tag->next_sibling()->tag) || $tag->next_sibling()->tag != 'p') {
        $index++;   
    }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_content);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level] => 0
            [inhalt] => Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [inhalt] => Text Level 2
More Text Level 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
            [inhalt] => Text Level 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
            [inhalt] => Text Level 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [level] => 0
            [inhalt] => Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
            [inhalt] => Text Level 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [level] => 0
            [inhalt] => Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
        )

)
```

Comment: I used find('p') because I need to obtain the order of the elements.

Comment: @user3142695 check out my revision, i hope this one fits

Comment: That's great! Thanks so far. I forgot something in my post. So I updated it. Please have a look at that. Hope you can solve that problem.

Comment: @user3142695 wow! your structure just got more complicated, check my revisions

Comment: @user3142695 i got the wrong logic, check out the revision